# Find "original" ListItem by reference to result of ListBox.SelectedItems?

Tags: c#, wpf, list

I got another problem with my ListBox.

I have a `class Entity` with `string Forename, Surname`.
Now I would like to show the user every `Entity` in a `ListBox personList`.
Therefor I do this:

```
foreach(Entity e in EntityHandler.entityList)
{
    personList.Items.Add(e.Name);
}
```

The user can select multiple entries of `personList`.

After clicking a button the application shall evaluate every selected entry in a `foreach`-loop.
For this I simply use

```
foreach(string selected in personList.SelectedItems)
{
    //do some stuff
}
```

The problem is now that there could be multiple `Entity` instances with exactly the same values.
The only static difference between every `Entity` is its `UID` but I don't want to write this ugly `UID` into their entries.

Is there a way how I could get the corresponding `Entity` out of the string value that I get from `SelectedItems`?
I read about overriding `GetHashCode()` and `Equal()` but I didn't get an idea why this should work?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should bind actual entitys to ListBox instead only names and set DisplayMemeber property of ListBox to "Name" property of Entity. This will give you direct access to ListBox items - Entities.

Take a look at this link on how to bind objects to ListBox:
http://sharpertutorials.com/list-box-data-binding/

Comment: Can't thank you as much as I would like Gregor :D
Really simply but effective solution to this problem!